# How to fix different behaviour in Date.toLocaleString method in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime-format

If someone can answer or encountered this during usage help me out. Seems like `hour12` is suppressing `hour` option.

Is there any way out to use `hour12` with `hour` and `minute` padded?
The other problem is the `am/pm` are coming in browser as lowercase while running over phantomjs is uppercase `AM/PM`

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(2);

console.log('without hour12 option ->', d.toLocaleString([], {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit'
}))
console.log('with hour12 option ->', d.toLocaleString([], {
  hour12: true,
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit'
}))
```